# Excel Import SQL - Value not suitable to be converted to a datetime data type

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql, import

I'm testing an import from mySql where I have an Account_Number that's '1000001' saved as a Varchar(255) (I guess in the event they add Numerical?)... either way.

When I import to Excel I get the error:

**Exception message:**

```
Value '1000001' is not suitable to be converted to a DateTime data type.

Exception thrown by:

MySqlDataTable.CopyTableData

Stack trace:
   at MySQL.ForExcel.Classes.MySqlDataType.GetValueAsDateTime(Object rawValue)
   at MySQL.ForExcel.Classes.MySqlDataColumn.GetInsertingValueForType(Object rawValue, Boolean escapeStringForTextTypes)
```

When I continue on - it shows a blank table in the screen.
When I finalize it - only one column shows of the 8

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I repeated the process again, and went into Advanced Options Where there is a Tab for date/time

One had mm/dd/yy hh:mm

I decided to drop the hh:mm this time and somehow it worked.

Would still like to know why it took a Varchar value and looked at it as a DateTimne

Comment: its either a numerical value of time, or bad data, that happens, to be a valid numerical form of a date